# Raspberry Pi Model B Threading. Run 2 python scripts concurrently

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I'm hoping you can help (as always). I'm making a photobooth and in short have a Python script to control the light (switches on for 30 seconds) and another to take 4 photos for the photobooth. 
I need to run the light script followed by the camera script 5 seconds later. I'm sure this is easy, but can't work it out. Here's what I've tried:

I'm not even sure if this is correct for the Raspberry Pi, but this is what I've tried inc. variations:

```
import threading
import time
def light():
    while time.time() <= start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target="sudo python /home/pi/python/light30.py").start()
def camera():
    while time.time() <= start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target="sudo python /home/pi/python/camtest.py").start()
start_time=time.time()+5
threading.Thread(target=light).start()
threading.Thread(target=camera).start()
```

Any help you can provide would be great, as I'm sure im being an idiot.

Comment: `Thread` target argument should be callable object, not string.

Comment: I wish I had the knowledge as you do Lukasz. How would I do this - I'm a relative n00b

Comment: why do you need to run the scripts with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments threading expects to run python code ... not a python file ... you can just use subprocess to accomplish that you want

```
import subprocess
import time

lights_proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/home/pi/python/light30.py"])
time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds
print subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/home/pi/python/camtest.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

the communicate call at the end just makes it block and wait for camtest.py to complete before exiting this script (as well as getting the output from the script)

Comment: Thanks so much Joran, that's what I couldn't get my head around.